# Trying to replace \t with \s with regex in Python, but as a result "Unhashable type:list" error

Tags: python, regex, compiler-errors

I am new to programming and have already checked other people's questions to make sure that I am using a good method to replace tabs with spaces, know my regex is correct, and also understand what exactly my error is ("Unhashable type 'list'). But even still, I'm at a loss of what to do. Any help would be great!

I have a large file that I have broken up into lines. Ultimately I will need to access the first 3 elements of each line. Currently when I print a line, without the additional re.sub line of code, I get something like this: ['blah\tblah\tblah'], when I want ['blah blah blah'].

My code to do this is

```
f = open(text.txt)
raw = f.read()
raw = raw.lower()

lines = raw.splitlines()
lines = re.sub(r'\t', lines, '\s')

print lines[0:2] #just to see the first few examples

f.close()
```

When I print the first few lines without the regex sub bit, it works fine. And then when I add that line in attempt to change the lines, I get the error. I understand that *lists* are changeable and thus can't be a hashed... but I'm not trying to work with a hash. I'm just trying to replace \t with \s in a large text file to make the program easier to work with. I don't think there is a problem with how I am changing \t's to \s's, because according to this error, any way I change it will break my code. What do I do?! Any help is super appreciated. :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of params present inside the `re.sub` function. And also note that you can't use regex `\s` as a second param in `re.sub` function. Syntax of re.sub must be `re.sub(regex,replacement,string)` .

```
lines = raw.splitlines()
lines = [re.sub(r'\t', ' ', line) for line in lines]
```

`raw.splitlines()` returns a list which was then assigned to a variable called `lines`. So you need to apply the `re.sub` function to each item present in the list, since `re.sub` won't directly be applied on a list.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! Can you explain why I need the "for line in lines" bit as well? Shouldn't it apply it globally without this bit?

Comment: lines is an array of string. regex work on string, not on an array

Comment: To be precise, `lines`is a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), not an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).